# Is adding Huffman tree or frequency table needed?

Tags: encoding, compression, decoding, huffman-code

I am learning about encoding and decoding and my instructor have a question for my homework?
That is: Are we still able to decode the Huffman compressed files without adding Huffman tree or the
frequency table to the files or not?

Comment: You need to figure out the possible relationship between the frequency table and the Huffman tree. If so, what is depending on what?

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of description of the Huffman code. However that description does not have to be the frequencies or the tree. Typically a [canonical Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code) is used, and all that is needed to describe the code is the bit lengths of the code for each symbol.